# Convert data into desired form using linux

Tags: linux, shell, unix, ubuntu

I have data in a tab separated file in the following form (filename.tsv):

```
#a      0 Espert       A trius
#b      9 def          J
```

I want to convert the data into the following form (I am introducing  here in every second line):

```
#@<a>
<0 Espert> <abc> <A trius>.
#@<b>
<9 def> <abc> <J>.
```

I am introducing  in every line. I know to do the same using python using csv module. But I am trying to learn linux commands, is there a way to do the same in linux terminal using linux commands like grep?

Comment: python runs fine on linux.

Comment: @JohnC I am trying to learn linux commands(like grep, etc) to do the same

Comment: You can't do it with grep.  Awk or bash will work though.  I advise that you do a bit more research and at least show some kind of attempt or the downvoters will get you.

Comment: What happened to the `9` from the second line, second column?

Comment: @CristianCiupitu Sorry that was a typo. Very sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`awk` seems like the right tool for the job:

```
awk '{ 
   printf "#@<%s>\n<%s %s> <abc> <%s%s%s>.\n", 
    substr($1,2),
    $2, 
    $3, 
    $4, 
    (length($5) ?  " " : ""),
    $5
 }' filename.tsv
```

- `awk` loops over all lines in the input file and breaks each line into fields by runs of tabs and/or spaces; `$1` refers to the first field, `$2`, to the second, ...
- `printf` functions the same as in C: a format (template) string containing placeholders is followed by corresponding arguments to substitute for the placeholders.
- `substr($1,2)` returns the substring of the 1st field starting at the 2nd character (i.e., `a` for the 1st line, `b` for the 2nd) - note that indices in `awk` are *1*-based.
- `(length($5) ? " " : "")` is a C-style ternary expression that returns a single space if the 5th field is nonempty, and an empty string otherwise.